# java script code not printing

Tags: javascript, html

The code should receive a sentence / string  and print it in reverse, if word or letter that wrote in the filter contained within the word belongs to a string - the word will not print.

The question, why my code is printing nothing?? tnx!

**for the input : hello what your name?  and filter o**

**the output should be: what name**

**(the word 'what' with underline)**

**the problem is that only one word show on the screen! not all of them**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myfunc()  {
     var count, i =0; 
     var phrase= document.getElementById('phrase').value;
     var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
     var arr = phrase.split(" ").reverse(); 
     for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].search(filter) == -1){
        count++; 
        if (count%2==1)
           document.getElementById('words').innerHTML="<span class='word'><u>"+ arr[i]+ "</u></span>";
        else
           document.getElementById('words').innerHTML="<span class='word'>"+arr[i]+ "</span>"; 
       }
}   
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML= count + "word(s) filtered out" ; 
}          
</script>
</head>
<body >
  <h1>Sentence Reverser!</h1>
  <div> Phrase: <input id="phrase" type="text" size="40"/></div>
  <div> Filter:    <input id="filter" type="text" size="10"/></div> 
  <div><button id="go" onclick="myfunc()"> Go! </button></div>
  <div id="words"></div>
  <div id="count"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a space in the declaration of filter...

Comment: `var count, i =0; ` won't set `count` to 0, it's `undefined`. Thus `count++;` will set count to `NaN`

Comment: ok,tnx now working better! but the word you not printing! only are...its should be yoe are

Answer (score 0):

For example you have an error (extra space):

```
var filter = document.ge tElementById('filter').value;
```

Becomes, obviously:

```
var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
```

**Suggest:** test on chrome, for instance, press F12 and take a look to console errors.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when you use *getElementById* DOM isn't build. You have to wait until it is build adding a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myfunc()  {
     var count=0, i =0; 
     var phrase= document.getElementById('phrase').value;
     var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
     var arr = phrase.split(" ").reverse(); 
     for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].search(filter) == -1){
        count++; 
        if (count%2==1)
           document.getElementById('words').innerHTML+=" <span class='word'><u>"+ arr[i]+ "</u></span>";
        else
           document.getElementById('words').innerHTML+=" <span class='word'>"+arr[i]+ "</span>"; 
       }
}   
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML= count + "word(s) filtered out" ; 
}          
</script>
</head>
<body >
  <h1>Sentence Reverser!</h1>
  <div> Phrase: <input id="phrase" type="text" size="40"/></div>
  <div> Filter:    <input id="filter" type="text" size="10"/></div> 
  <div><button id="go" onclick="myfunc()"> Go! </button></div>
  <div id="words"></div>
  <div id="count"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using "indexOf" as in my answer above, instead of "search"

Comment: but if my filter is the letter h why cant i use search ?

Comment: I have revised my answer and also tested it, it works. Please try

Comment: I guess you have not taken my updated code, because I tried with the inputs that you used "hello what your name" and able to output "name what" with correct count of 2 words filtered out for "hello, your" both contain 'o'

Comment: Notice the change for **innerHTML+=** instead of **innerHTML=**  when you want multiple words to be printed then you have to append using the += operator